# Why the cache in cefsharp is so large?

Tags: caching, cefsharp

I'm new in CefSharp, and i just made my first simple program. 
I'd like to know, why my cache file is 44mb? O.O
Is there a way to save only the login in just one site?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't provide a `CachePath` then an `InMemory` cache will be used, you can then subsequently just set the path for cookies. Example is below.

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L134

As for the `Cache` size, if you examine the cache folder, you'll see that things like `Fonts` get cached, they take up a lot of space. So the usage your seeing it normal and nothing to worry about. This will be on par with an equivalent version of `Chrome`.

**EDIT**: See Sample Below

```
Cef.OnContextInitialized = delegate
{
    var cookieManager = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
    cookieManager.SetStoragePath("cookies", true);
};

Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings()
{
    PersistSessionCookies = true,
});
```